# ReLoad Video in Jquery dialog after .destroy

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I want to .destroy the video instance once the dialog is closed but then be able to click the link and video appears again. Currently once I close the dialog when I try to click on the link the video will not relaunch. Any help is most appreciated.

```
$(function(){

                $('#dialog').dialog({
                    open: function() { $(".ui-dialog").addClass("ui-dialog-shadow"); },
                    autoOpen: false,
                    width: 660,
                    height: 400,
                    modal: true,
                    close: function() {
    $(this).dialog('destroy').append('#dialog');
},

                });

                $('#dialog_link').click(function(){
                    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
                    return false;
                });

                $('#dialog_link, ul#icons li').hover(
                    function() { $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover'); },
                    function() { $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover'); }
                );

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using this as your close function.

```
close: function() {
    if( ! $(this).length ) {
         $('body').append('<div id="dialog"></div>');
    }
},
```

Comment: it works, sort of - but only problem is you continue to hear the video (the audio part) play in the background. Once you close the dialog I want the video to close (which it does) AND stop the audio. Thanks - Doug